# Jolt: How to level-up elements from an object?

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I have the following JSON :

```json
{
  "Content": [
    {
      "CandidateFirstName": "Nagu",
      "Applications": {
        "ApplicationId": "456",
        "Sarasa": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "CandidateFirstName": "Deleted",
      "Applications": {
        "ApplicationId": "123",
        "Sarasa": "test2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I'd like to have the following output:

```json
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Nagu",
    "ApplicationsId": "456",
    "Sarasa": "test"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Deleted",
    "ApplicationsId": "123",
    "Sarasa": "test2"
  }
]
```

I'm close with the following jolt, but I'm not being able to remove the object "Applications":

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "CandidateFirstName": "[&1].FirstName",
          "Applications": "[&1].Applications"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Do you know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you were quite close. You have to just add one more level of nested section for **Applications** section

```
[
 {
 "operation": "shift",
 "spec": {
  "Content": {
    "*": {
      "CandidateFirstName": "[&1].FirstName",
      "Applications": {
         "*": "[&2].&"
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this and works great :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use two consecutive **shift** transformation specs

```json
[
  {//get individual objects nested within square brackets
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "Applications": {
            "@1,CandidateFirstName": "&2[#1].FirstName",
            "*": "&2[#2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of the keys of index values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or use a single spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "Candidate*": "[#2].FirstName",// the expression "&(0,1)" replicates the literal extracted from the current( 0th ) level of the 1st asterisk(might be multiple) which is stated on the LHS 
          "@Applications.ApplicationId": "[#2].ApplicationId",
          "@Applications.Sarasa": "[#2].Sarasa"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **`[#2]`**, *as having a **#** wildcard and nested within square brackets* and staying on the right-hand-side, represents traversing one colon(**`:`**), and one opening curly brace **`{`** those makes **2** in order to reach the level of the indexes of the **`Content`** array to grab them.

Yet, there's another method as follows :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "Appl*": {// represents the key of the node starts with "Appl" in order to shorten the literal "Applications"
            "@1,CandidateFirstName": "[&2].FirstName",// need to go one level up to get the value of the "CandidateFirstName" attribute
            "*": "[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **`[&2]`** on the RHS represents traversing two opening curly braces in contrast to the **`[#2]`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short and concise spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Candidate*": "[&1].&(0,1)",
          "*": {
            "*": "[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```